# java rename file before upload

Tags: java, android

I have a problem, **I have source code like this**

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
     SharedPreferences myPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String upLoadServerUri = new String(myPref.getString("serverURL", Constants.URL)+"/upload.php");
    String fileName = picturePath;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;  
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
    File sourceFile = new File(picturePath);
```

How to rename file on  *picturePath*  before uploaded.
Thank You

Comment: Probably `File#renameTo`!

Comment: possible duplicate of [android, How to rename a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424997/android-how-to-rename-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

You could try by putting this in the begging of the function:

```
File renamed =new File(sourceFileUri);
renamed.renameTo(new File("newfile.png"));
```

And then you will call renamed.getAbsolutePath(); instead of sourceFileUri.