# how to rename a file in android

Tags: java, android, file

Help me in converting a file name to own file name.

I tried the following but it did not work:

```
File file = new File("27.mp4");
File file1 = new File("abcd");
file1.rename(file);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would it be possible for you to provide the specific errors that you are getting? Please do take some time to read through [How to Ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Comment: Try to follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424997/android-how-to-rename-a-file

Answer (score 1):

The method is called `renameTo`:

```
File file = new File("27.mp4");
File file1 = new File("abcd");
file1.renameTo(file);
```

Comment: Nope, this doesn't rename the old file