# How to rename the user file name at the Users directory?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

After installing **Android Studio** the `SDK` location was set to `C:\Users\Omar Abdelhafiz\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`,

but it shows me a warning saying `Android SDK location should not contain white space, as this can cause problems with the NDK tools.`

So I want to change the directory to `Omar_Abdelhafiz` instead of `Omar Abdelhafiz`.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [i hope this link will help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424997/android-how-to-rename-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually go to the directory and change your folder name after change your sdk folder path will be like this

C:\Users\Omar_Abdelhafiz\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Now come to your Android Studio:
**File**>>**Settings**>>**Appearance & Behavior**>**System Settings**>**Android SDK**>>Now in Right side panel there will be **Android SDK Location**
Change that with your new SDK path, then **Apply** and **OK** click

**Note:** Next is you have to change in your system environment variables if you are using windows for platform tools path.
This is my platform tools path which I put in windows system enviornment variables path E:\Rahul\AndroidTool\ANDROID_SDK\sdk\platform-tools

To set system environment variable path for platform tools follow [Set the Android SDK Home Environment Variable](http://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/visualizer/visualizer_user_guide/Content/SUG_Android.htm)

It's done

[image]

Comment: Do you think I haven't tried that? you can't change the name manually.

Comment: What issue you faced after this? Actually I was also getting this issue previously as you can see my new path in image. Previously my path was having Android Tools and now it's having AndroidTools

Comment: I simply couldn't change the directory manually, try it go to the users directory right click on a user you can't find the rename option

Comment: But what is the need to keep Android SDK in C:\Users\ folder you can use it in another folder as I am using it in E: drive

Comment: I just wanted to keep the default, do you see I should put it in another directory

Comment: Are you not able to rename other folders as well in C:\Users\ directory? Once check because may be it can be issue with related to edit permission for you. Because I am able to rename any folder in my C:\users drive

Comment: I can't rename this user and public file, But The other files can be renamed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132550/discussion-between-ready-android-and-omar-abdelhafiz).