# How to share pdf with title[should not show UNTITLED]

Tags: android

the following code is the sharing pdf with UNTITLED.pdf
how to name the pdf

```
 Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.setType("application/pdf");
                String shareMessage= "dummy";
               shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage);
              sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse(targetPdf));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "dummy"));
```

what I should put in putextra to change the shared pdf from UNTITLTED to dummy?

Comment: You can't change name of the PDF by using `Intent` try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32155722/4394827

Comment: Hello Hemanth, I have tried some of the codes from the above link which u have suggested me for renaming the file but it wasn’t helpful. I would like to brief you with my question again. I have pdf file location which saved into pdffile. Then checking file path exists or not. Over here I wrote if file path exists then renameTo method and saving it. Can you write what I am missing here plz

Answer (score 0):

The activity that handles the `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` can do what it wants. There is no way to force it to do anything, in part because there are *thousands* of `ACTION_SEND` activities, each created by a different development team. So,

- Some might pay attention to your `EXTRA_TEXT`, and some might not, as the `ACTION_SEND` specification only supports *either* `EXTRA_TEXT` or `EXTRA_STREAM`, and you are using both
- Some might look at the last path segment of the `Uri` and assume that it is some sort of filename; others might not

So, populate the `Intent` as you are, perhaps tweak the values a bit, and otherwise just live with it.